# javascript parseInt through map

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting

I have some expressions which behave in a strange way:

```
"600x400".split('x').map(parseInt)
"600x400".split('x').map(parseFloat)
```

And

```
"0,1,0,0,0,1".split(',').map(parseInt)
"0,1,0,0,0,1".split(',').map(parseFloat)
```

Applying **parseInt** to the arrays of strings makes the second element **NaN** while **parseFloat** gives the right number.

Bug in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow function :

```
"600x400".split('x').map( x => parseInt(x))
[ 600, 400 ]
```

Comment: Yes, this makes the code work preperly, but what is the reason why my codes is incorrect ?